# filter object by property in nodejs

Tags: node.js, filter

My object looks like that :

```
    {
    "performance": {...},
    "a": "",
    "b": "N",
    "c": true,
    "groups": [
      {
        "acctTypes": [
          {
            "xxx": "xxx",
            "ttt": "ttt",
            "accounts": [
            {
              ...
            },
            {
              ...
            },
            {
              ...
            }
            ],
          },
          {
            "acctTypes": [
              {
                "xxx": "xxx",
                "ttt": "ttt",
                "accounts": [
                  {
                    ...
                  },
                  {
                    ...
                  },
                  {
                    ...
                  },
                  {
                    ...
                  },
                  {
                    ...
                  }
                ],
              },
    ],
    "summary": [
      {
        ...
      },
      {
        ...
      }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to pull all the "accounts" from it (looked into _js and lodash - but couldn't find anything relevant)

the result should be an object / array which contains all the accounts

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the obj is structured in a similar way further down, this might work for you

```js
obj = {
 "performance": {},
 "a": "",
 "b": "N",
 "c": true,
 "groups": [
 {
  "acctTypes": [
   {
    "xxx": "xxx",
    "ttt": "ttt",
    "accounts": [
     {
      a:1
     },
     {
      b:2
     }
    ],
   },
   {
    "acctTypes": [
     {
      "xxx": "xxx",
      "ttt": "ttt",
      "accounts": [
       {
        c:3
       },
       {
        d:4
       }
      ],
     },
    ],
    "summary": [
     {

     },
     {
     }
    ]
   }]}]}

let filtered = obj.groups.reduce(key => key.accounts).acctTypes
let accounts = []
filtered.map(key => {
 if (key.accounts) {
  accounts.push(...key.accounts)
 } else if (key.acctTypes){
  accounts.push(...key.acctTypes[0].accounts)
 }
})
console.log(accounts)
```

I've added data to accounts for some PoC.
I test whether each item in `filtered` contains an `accounts` key or an `acctTypes` which in turn should include an `accounts` key, then add the values to the `accounts` array using ES6 spreading.

Comment: Thanks , worked perfectly :) I'll try to achieve it with lodash / "_" for practice ...